# Mapper and reducer functions in python

Tags: python, hadoop

I want to know whether there is anything wrong with my mapper and reducer functions below. It is a part of project in Udacity's intro to data science course

```
def mapper():
    dic={}
    for line in sys.stdin:
        data=line.strip().split(" ")
        for i in data:
            dic[i]=1
    for key, value in dic.iteritems():
        print key,'\t', value
```

Here values are input as string with words separated by a space and function returns a dictionary with each word of the string as the 'key' and it's counting 1 as the 'value'.

```
def reducer():
    dic={}
    for line in sys.stdin:
        data=line.strip().split('\t')
        if data[0] in dic.keys():
            dic[data[0]]+=1
        else:
            dic[data[0]]=data[1]
    for key, value in dic.iteritems():
        print key,'\t',value
```

Here values are inputted as a string consisting of the word and count 1 separated by a tab. Both functions are executed differently. I'm not getting the correct output.

Comment: What output are you getting?
What output are you expecting?
Also... for both functions, you must have an `import sys` somewhere, but that is not shown in your code above.

Comment: i've written import sys in my code..just forgot to mention it here!

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you told us something about the output you expect, but in `dic[data[0]]=data[1]` the value `data[1]` is a string so you won't be able to add a number such as `1` to it.

Also, surely the point of a reducer is that it may run multiple times when the input count isn't always going to be `1`, you may want to add the actual value rather than just incrementing.

```
def reducer():
    dic=collections.defaultdict(int)
    for line in sys.stdin:
        key, value=line.strip().split('\t')
        dic[key] += int(value)
    for key, value in dic.iteritems():
        print key,'\t',value
```

Comment: actually my output doesn't match the solution. the count of the words resulted from my functions is different. i think there is some error in adding values but i can't figure it out.